# single-row subquery returns more than one row - how to find the duplicate?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

iam not a big ORACLE - SQL Expert, so i hope someone knows a good way to find the "duplicate" record wich is causing the: **single-row subquery returns more than one row** error.

This my Statement:

```
    SELECT
    CAST(af.SAP_SID AS VARCHAR2(4000)) APP_ID,
    (SELECT DR_OPTION
       FROM
          DR_OPTIONS 
       WHERE DR_OPTIONS.ID = (
            select dr_option from applications where applications.sap_sid = af.sap_sid)) DR_OPTION
FROM
    APPLICATIONS_FILER_VIEW af
```

it works on my test system, so iam "sure" there must be an error inside the available data records, but i have no idea how to find those ..

Comment: execute the inner queries on their own to see what they return..

Comment: try with this query: `select applications.sap_sid, count(dr_option) from applications group by applications.sap_sid having count(dr_option) > 1` this should give you the sap_sid of the duplicated rows

Comment: @ A.B.Cade's answer should be copied to the answers section and IMHO accepted.  It is the general solution to this problem.

Comment: Followed your suggestion @Karl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this query:

```
select applications.sap_sid, count(dr_option) 
from applications 
group by applications.sap_sid 
having count(dr_option) > 1
```

This should give you the sap_sid of the duplicated rows

Comment: hum cant find the failure (-:

Comment: @ArneRie, No rows were found by the query ?

Comment: There are rows found, but altough on the test system were the full query is working (-: The query works with "IN" but i think thats not the correct solution :-)

Comment: As long as you have more than one dr_option for a sap_id it won't work... try to see what these values are, maybe they are always the same and you can use distinct or see if `IN` is ok for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest simplifying your query:

```
SELECT      CAST(af.SAP_SID AS VARCHAR2(4000)) APP_ID,
            dr.DR_OPTION
FROM        APPLICATIONS_FILER_VIEW af
INNER JOIN  applications a ON af.sap_sid = a.sap_sid
INNER JOIN  DR_OPTIONS dr ON a.dr_option = dr.ID
```

Comment: Running the query above should help you to identity the duplicate row.

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate what you get when you run:

```
select dr_option from applications where applications.sap_sid = af.sap_sid
```

but you could force only one row to be returned (I see this as being a fudge and would not recommend using it at least add an order by to have some control over the row being returned) with something like:

```
SELECT
CAST(af.SAP_SID AS VARCHAR2(4000)) APP_ID,
(SELECT DR_OPTION
   FROM
      DR_OPTIONS 
   WHERE DR_OPTIONS.ID = (
        select dr_option 
        from applications 
        where applications.sap_sid = af.sap_sid
            and rownumber = 1)
   ) DR_OPTION
FROM
   APPLICATIONS_FILER_VIEW af
```

(not tested just googled how to limit results in oracle)

If you fix the data issue (as per A.B.Cades comment) then I would recommend converting it to use joins as per weenoid's answer. this would also highlight other data issues that may arise in the future.

IN SHORT: I have never fixed anything in this way.. the real answer is to investigate the multiple rows returned and decide what you want to do maybe:

1. add more where clauses
2. order the results and only select top row
3. actually keep the duplicates as they represent a scenario you have not thought of before

Comment: The fact that he got more than one result doesn't mean they're all the same (otherwise he could use distinct). What you can recomend (though it may not be what he wants) is to use `in` instead of `=`

Comment: @A.B.Cade sorry do you mean `rownumber in 1` or `DR_OPTIONS.ID IN (`

Comment: `... WHERE DR_OPTIONS.ID IN (select dr_option from applications where applications.sap_sid = af.sap_sid)`  (remove the `rownumber = 1`)

Comment: ah.. i was trying to force there to be only one row returned.